# how does python assign value to inner function

Tags: python, function

Can someone please explain how python assigned the value below to `y`. I understand how the function works but I do not understand how the function call `a(10)` assigns its value `y`.

```
def outside(x):
    def inside(y):
        return x ** y
    return inside

a = outside(2)

a(10)
```

Comment: C'mon guys, did you even read the question you've marked this one a duplicate of?

Comment: Read about decorators.

Comment: @scopa, it is a function factory, outside  is basically passed the exponent to raise to and then using a(10) you are calling the inner function where y is raised to a power of x. If you `print a.__closure__` you will see python creates a closure to refer to that object.

Answer (score 3):

In this code `a()` is effectively an alias for `inside()`, with the value of `x` fixed at `2`.

Thus `a(10)` is essentially `inside(10)`, i.e. the value of `y` is `10`.

Since `x` is `2` and `y` is `10`, `a(10)` returns `2 ** 10` (1024).

This type of construct is used extensively in Python decorators. I'd recommend [Understanding Python Decorators in 12 Easy Steps!](http://simeonfranklin.com/blog/2012/jul/1/python-decorators-in-12-steps/) as a nice introduction. Among other things it explains how Python functions are first-class objects and can be assigned to variables, passed as arguments to other functions etc.

Comment: He called his function `inside` not `inner`

Comment: Thanks I understand that y is being assigned the value 10. I am not clear on how python accepts a() as an alias.

Comment: @scopa: Have a read of the decorator tutorial I've linked to in the answer. Perhaps it'll answer some question.

Answer (score 1):

What happens, step by step:

1. You're calling the `outside` function with `x = 2`.
2. `outside` returns the function `inside` defined in the context of `x` being `2`.
3. So now, `a` contains the function: `def inside(y): return 2 ** y`
4. You're calling `a(10)`, which is, recalling step 3, `inside(10)`.

This feature is called [*Functions as First-Class Objects*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/First-class_function) - it basically means that functions are like class instances, that can hold state, and can be passed in variables and arguments, just like anything else. Note the following example:

```
>>> def x():
...     pass
...
>>> x
<function x at 0x02F91A30>  # <-- function's address
>>> type(x)
<type 'function'>
>>>
>>> y = x
>>> type(y)
<type 'function'>
>>> y
<function x at 0x02F91A30>  # <-- the same address
>>>
```